# Getting unexpected token error in vercel while deploying (runs fine in development)

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, vercel

How to resolve this I am not sure so please help, thank you in advance

```js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/post-payload.js:17:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
Deployment completed
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version of next.js I downgraded it and it works fine now

Comment: What version did you roll back to?

Answer (score 1):

You Node.js 16.8 or later.

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation

You can see this in the System Requirement.